# Reducing cursor size in GIMP

Tags: linux-mint, gimp, mouse-cursor

Using GIMP 2.10.18 on Linux Mint. The cursor is huge as shown in the attached image, making it difficult to do work with any kind of precision. Is there a way to reduce the size? I've worked with GIMP in Windows and its cursor is of a normal size (similar to the regular mouse pointer). I've checked over preferences in GIMP, and can't find anything about cursor size.

My cursor is normal-sized in all other applications, so I believe this to be a GIMP-specific issue.

[image]